# Source of Zohar on Resurrection of the Dead

Tags: sources-mekorot, zohar

Rabbi Nachman Bulman, in his book *[Longing for Dawn](https://www.feldheim.com/longing-for-dawn.html)* (page 78) writes the following:

> The Zohar says that at the Resurrection of the Dead each person will
>   return with the same soul and the same body he had in his earlier
>   life, but that the soul and the body will then be perfect and possess
>   an understanding which will enable them to perceive everything they
>   weren't able to comprehend when alive in this world. The shape and
>   characteristics of the body will be the same as they were before
>   death, including even the physical blemishes the person had, which
>   will be instantly healed

Does anyone happen to know where in the *Zohar* can this statement be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the teaching of Rabbi Elazar from Tikkunei Zohar, Tikkun 40, page 81a (or as [Sefaria lists it 82b](https://www.sefaria.org/Tikkunei_Zohar.82a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) which says:

> אָמַר רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר, תָּא חֲזִי, בְּשַׁעִִתָּא דְזָמִין קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא לְאַחָיָיא מֵיתַיָּא, כָּל אִינוּן נִשְׁמָתִין דְּיִתְעָרוּן, **כֻּלְּהוֹן יְקוּמוּן בְּהַהוּא דִיּוֹקְנָא מַמָּשׁ דַּהֲווֹ בְּהַאי עָלְמָא**, וְנָחִית לוֹן קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא וְקָרָא לוֹן בִּשְׁמָהָן, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב (ישעיה מ כו) לְכֻלָּם בְּשֵׁם יִקְרָא, וְכָל נִשְׁמָתָא תֵּיעוּל לְדוּכְתָּהָא, **וִיקוּמוּן בְּקִיּוּמָא בְּעָלְמָא כְּדְקָא חַזִי, וּכְדֵין יְהֵא עָלְמָא שְׁלִים**, וְעַל הַהוּא זִמְנָא כְּתִיב (שם כה ח) **וְחֶרְפַּת עַמּוֹ יָסִיר**, דָּא יֵצֶר הָרָע דְּאַחְשִׁיךְ אַפֵּי דְבַר נַשׁ וְשַׁלִּיט בֵּיהּ.

אָמַר רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר: בֹּא וּרְאֵה, בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁעָתִיד הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְהַחֲיוֹת אֶת הַמֵּתִים, כָּל אוֹתָן נְשָׁמוֹת שֶׁיִּתְעוֹרְרוּ, כֻּלָּם יָקוּמוּ בְּאוֹתוֹ דְּמוּת מַמָּשׁ שֶׁהָיוּ בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה, וּמוֹרִיד אוֹתָן הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא וְקוֹרֵא לָהֶם בַּשֵּׁמוֹת, זֶהוּ שֶׁכָּתוּב לְכֻלָּם בְּשֵׁם יִקְרָא. וְכָל נְשָׁמָה תִּכָּנֵס לִמְקוֹמָהּ, וְיַעַמְדוּ בְקִיּוּם בָּעוֹלָם כָּרָאוּי, וְאָז יִהְיֶה הָעוֹלָם שָׁלֵם, וְעַל אוֹתוֹ זְמַן כָּתוּב וְחֶרְפַּת עַמּוֹ יָסִיר, זֶה יֵצֶר הָרָע שֶׁמַּחְשִׁיךְ פְּנֵי הָאָדָם וְשׁוֹלֵט בּוֹ.

And then the text continues and says:

> וְאִתְנְהִיר הַהוּא נְהוֹרָא דְזַמִּין לְאַנְהָרָא לְצַדִּיקַיָּא, דַהֲוָה קַמֵּיהּ גָּנִיז מִיּוֹמָא דְאִתְבְּרִי עָלְמָא, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב (בראשית א ד) וַיַּרְא אלהי''ם אֶת הָאוֹר כִּי טוֹב, בֵּיהּ זָמִין קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא לְאַחָיָא מֵיתַיָּא, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב (מלאכי ג כ) **וְזָרְחָה לָכֶם יִרְאֵי שְׁמִי שֶׁמֶשׁ צְדָקָה וּמַרְפֵּא, וּכְדֵין יִתְגַּבַּר טוֹב בְּעָלְמָא, וְהַהוּא דְאִתְקְרֵי רָע יִתְעֲבַר מֵעָלְמָא**, וּכְדֵין אִינוּן גּוּפִין קַדְמָאִין לִיהווּ כְלָא הֲווֹ.

וּמֵאִיר אוֹתוֹ הָאוֹר שֶׁעָתִיד לְהָאִיר לַצַּדִּיקִים, שֶׁהָיָה גָנוּז לְפָנָיו מִיּוֹם שֶׁנִּבְרָא הָעוֹלָם, זֶהוּ שֶׁכָּתוּב וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים אֶת הָאוֹר כִּי טוֹב, בּוֹ עָתִיד הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְהַחֲיוֹת מֵתִים, זֶהוּ שֶׁכָּתוּב וְזָרְחָה לָכֶם יִרְאֵי שְׁמִי שֶׁמֶשׁ צְדָקָה וּמַרְפֵּא, וְאָז יִתְגַּבֵּר הַטּוֹב בָּעוֹלָם, וְאוֹתוֹ שֶׁנִּקְרָא רָע יַעֲבֹר מִן הָעוֹלָם, וְאָז אוֹתָם גּוּפוֹת רִאשׁוֹנִים יִהְיוּ כְלֹא הָיוּ.

Comment: @ Yaacov Deane: Thank you for finding the source!